# SSL not fully secured (How to find non https links)?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, mixed-content

I changed from `http` to `https` but the message is showing that it is not fully secured. I am using `Wordpress`.

When I click view page source the home menu still shows http:// for the home page and a few others.

However in the database and settings, I could not find any http links 
any suggestions?

Site is:
https://androidage.net/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set all your links, especially, to images to use https.  If you are comfortable running SQL commands and backup your database beforehand, you can do this using phpMyAdmin and run a similar SQL command:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'http://sourcedomain.com/','https://sourcedomain.com/');
```

You will need to change the 'wp_' prefix to whatever prefix you are using for your database.

Otherwise there should be some plugins that will do it.  A quick search brought up this one:  [Wordpress HTTPS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/)